# Groovy - as vs (cast)

Tags: groovy, compile-static

Is there any practical difference between the following two approaches to casting:

`result.count = (int) response['hits']['total']`

vs

`result.count = response['hits']['total'] as int`

I'm using `@CompileStatic` and the compiler is wanting me to do the cast - which got me wondering if there was any performance or practical difference between the two notations.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The main difference is casting uses the concept of inheritance to do the conversion where the `as` operator is a custom converter that might or might not use the concepts of inheritance.

***Which one is faster?***
It depends on the converter method implementation.

### Casting

> Well, all casting really means is taking an Object of one particular
>   type and “turning it into” another Object type. This process is called
>   casting a variable.

E.g:

```
Object object = new Car();
Car car = (Car)object;
```

As we can see on the example we are casting an object of class `Object` into a `Car` because we know that the object is instance of `Car` deep down.

But we cant do the following unless `Car` is subclass of `Bicycle` which in fact does not make any sense (you will get `ClassCastException` in this case):

```
Object object = new Car();
Bicycle bicycle = (Bicycle)object;
```

### `as` Operator

> In Groovy we can override the method asType() to convert an object
>   into another type. We can use the method asType() in our code to
>   invoke the conversion, but we can even make it shorter and use as.

In groovy to use the `as` operator the left hand operand must implement this method:

```
Object asType(Class clazz) {
        //code here
    }
```

As you can see the method accepts an instance of `Class` and implements a custom converter so basically you can convert `Object` to `Car` or `Car` to `Bicycle` if you want it all depends on your implementation.